# How do I check for availability of record for a user and if available, re-enter for security?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

We have a need to use Ajax to  make a call to a php file to check for availability of record from the database.

If record exists, ask a user to reconfirm the token number by entering again into another box.

If  they match, the user continues on with filling rest of form.

If they don't match, an error is raised.

I have two separate files that accomplish the dual goal of checking availability from the db and comparing that record by asking user to re-enter that same number.

However, I would like to combine the two files into one.

Could someone please guide me?

This first file uses ajax to make a call to a php file to check for availability of records.

It is called index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Check Availability of Token</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#token").blur(function()
    {
        //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn(1000);
        //check the token exists or not from ajax
        $.post("checkToken.php",{ user_token:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='no') //if token not avaiable
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            {
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('Token exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
            });
          }
          else
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
            {
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('Token does not exist').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);
            });
          }

        });

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<br>
<br>
<div align="center">
<div class="top" > Check Availability of token - <strong>Token &quot;roshan&quot;, &quot;mike&quot; ,&quot;jason&quot; exists</strong><br>
  Please move the focus out of the box to check the availability of token.
</div>
<div >
   Token : <input name="token" type="text" id="token" value="" maxlength="15" />
   <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The second file is called tokencompare.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - Compare Validate token</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("#confirm_token").parent().hide();
$("#token").keydown(function() {
    var self = this, $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ( $.trim(self.value) != "" && !$self.is(".error") ) {
            $("#confirm_token").parent().show();
            return;
        }
        $("#confirm_token").val('').parent().hide();
    },0);
});

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#tokenval").validate({
    rules: {
        token: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        confirm_token: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#token"
        }
    },
    messages: {},
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("submitted");
    }
});
});//]]>

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form class="cmxform" id="tokenval" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="token">token</label>
            <input id="token" name="token" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="confirm_token">Confirm token</label>
            <input id="confirm_token" name="confirm_token" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How is the first token selected?

Comment: @TimSPQR, the user enters the first token into a textbox. That's on index.html.

Then upon moving focus away from the box (onblur), then a message as to whether token exists or not is dispensed.

On the php file, if exists, then results="yes", otherwise, results="no"

I am ok with the php bit.

Thank you

Comment: Hmmm...so the user only has to enter the token one-time, and if it exists, OK, if not OK. So one ajax query to extract an entire row from the db, and it exists or doesn't. Why do they need to reconfirm the token if they've already typed it in? Why not have them type it in twice, like a password change operation? Then a single call to the db.

Comment: @TimSPQR, that's a fantastic question. I asked the same question myself.

Infact, if you run the second file that I posted called tokencompare.html, it is doing just that.

Their only issue is that the user gets sent the token via an email as the token is getting inserted into the db.

So, as the user is entering the token, they would want the db to validate that yes, it is a valid token and then to re-enter for security.

Didn't make sense but I am trying to see if it is doable.

Thanks again

Comment: Ok, so the two token entries are separated by time (short or long), so you'll probably need a double query, unless the time is always very short. You could store a variable locally, and hope the user doesn't refresh the screen, or you could do a cookie.

Comment: @TimSPQR, no wrong approach.

All I would need is query the db once just to validate the existence of the token.

Once it is confirmed that the token exists, then I use jquery or ajax onblur to reconfirm what the user already typed.

I am just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Now I'm very confused. Who creates the token? Why is it emailed to the user?

Comment: @TimSPQR, let's take a step back.

If you run the first part of the code I posted above, you will see that it works in that if you enter a token that doesn't exist, upon moving focus away from textbox, it let's you know if that token exists or not. That's all that should matter to us here because either way, user still has to enter it into a textbox.

My question is do you know how I can extend that by adding another box that allows user to enter same token again to reconfirm that is it the same and upon moving focus, it confirms it is the same or not?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your upper code. http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vmgr2/. You have already called the db once to see if the token exists. If they typed it wrong, then you'll have to call the db to see again. The only way I can see to solve your problem is a single db call that reads EVERY token, keeps it on client side, and let's them reenter tokens until you find the right one.

Comment: OK, @TimSPQR, I get your point but my point is can I add another textbox there so that assume that the token does exist, instead popping up another message that says, "token exists", it will display another textbox.

Let me worry about re-querying the db.

Is it possible that you can do that?

The code for doing this is already in the second code I posted.

I just need help integrating the two.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vmgr2/7/) does what you want.

The "real" token is xxxxx.

The format for any token is five characters. The code strips leading and trailing zeros.

So you can start with xxxxx and watch what happens.

Then xxx.

Then rrr

Then rrrrr.

JS

```
var validtoken = "xxxxx";

$('#checkme').click(function(){
     $('#messagediv').html('');
     var firsttoken = $('#token1').val();
     firsttoken = firsttoken.trim();

    if( firsttoken.length !== 5)
      {
       $('#messagediv').html('The token has an incorrect format<br /> Please reenter');
       $('#token1').val('');    
       } else {
                if (firsttoken == validtoken)
                  {
                   $('#messagediv').html('Your token exists<br /> click PROCEED for the next step');
                   $('.proceed').css('display', 'block');
                   } else {
                   $('.errordiv').css('display', 'block');
                           }
               }
                             A});

$('#proceed').click(function(){
  $('#token1').val('');     
  $('.proceed').css('display', 'none');
  $('#messagediv').html('');
  alert('And the next step is....');
                                });

$('#confirm').click(function(){
  var confirmtoken1 = $('#token1').val();
  var confirmtoken2 = $('#token2').val();

  if(confirmtoken1 == confirmtoken2)    
    { $('#token1').val('');  
      $('#token2').val('');      
      $('.proceed').css('display', 'none');
      $('#messagediv').html('');
      alert('Confirmed. And the next step is....');
    } else {
            $('#token1').val('');  
            $('#token2').val('');      
            $('.proceed').css('display', 'none');
            $('.errordiv').css('display', 'none');
            $('#messagediv').html('tokens do not match. Reenter');
           }
                              });
```

Comment: Very nice effort indeed.

Problem though is that we don't want to click a button until we are ready to submit to the database.

Will it be easier if we eliminate one step?

Instead of comparing the value in first box with value in second box, maybe we can just compare the value with the value from database.If a match, we continue to enter values into two or three more boxes before we click the submit button.

Is this easier?

Thanks sir

Comment: Ok, but you can take and do anything you want with it. You can change  the click to .blur, you can change the names of the buttons to anything you want. I'm getting the hint that perhaps you didn't write the code above...right? And you just wanted someone to rewrite the frontend...right?

Comment: I wrote the second part of the code. That code uses the onblur. You enter first token and when you move focus away from the box, it opens the second and ask that you reconfirm the token you just entered. That works as stated earlier. The problem I wanted that initial check to come from the db us ajax onblur and that's what the second code does but I didn't write that.

Thanks for your help anyway.